# HttpServlet - add context to html page

Tags: java, html, servlets, web-applications

I want to understand **how a html page can call a servlet to add elements to its body** but i can't find the right way to achieve that can you give me or refer me to an example of doing this?

---

Example:

lets suppose there is an html page with a form that contains a button with:

```
 name="I am"
 value="the button"
```

---

Example scenario:

> 1. click this button
> 2. call a servlet
> 3. add a message to this page saying *"I am the button"*

---

> *many thanks for any guidance.*

Comment: What have you achieved by now?

Comment: This scenario is preferred to using `Jquery`'s `Ajax` to talk to the servlet. retrieve data and add elem to the page using Jquery again, it's easy, but you should knock in some code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#btn").click(function() {
  $.post("buttonServlet", function (response) {
   alert(response);
  });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My Button</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="button" name="btn" id ="btn" value="The Button" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/buttonServlet")
public class ButtonServlet extends HttpServlet {    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("I am the button");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Ajax.

In your html page contain a button ,

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" value="the button" name="I am" onclick="showMsg()" />
```

Implement ajax,

```
function showMsg() {
      var buttonMsg =  document.getElementById("button1").name +  document.getElementById("button1").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: "yourservlet",
            type: "post",
            data:{'msgVar': buttonMsg} ,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
              //depends on the method you want to show your message
              //the variable data contain the message you want
              alert(data); //to show in popout message
            }
        });

    }
```

Assuming your servlet POST method contain following variable

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String message = request.getparameter("msgVar");
out.println(message);
```